# Swift application crashes when loading Admob banner

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I am trying to implement a Admob Banner in my iOS 15 app but I am running into some issues with that. When I am launching my app it just crashes with the following error:

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee35ddff8)

If I remove the call of the banner I get the following error:

```
2021-11-26 08:01:47.754819+0100 AdMobTest[26286:817324] [Client] Synchronous remote object proxy returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
```

It would be awesome if someone could help with my problem :)
Here are is my code:
info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>
<string>ca-app-pub-5691844305658550~9908946978</string>
<key>SKAdNetworkItems</key>
<array>
<dict>
<key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
<string>cstr6suwn9.skadnetwork</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
<string>4fzdc2evr5.skadnetwork</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
<string>2fnua5tdw4.skadnetwork</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
<string>ydx93a7ass.skadnetwork</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
<string>5a6flpkh64.skadnetwork</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
<string>p78axxw29g.skadnetwork</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
<string>v72qych5uu.skadnetwork</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
<string>c6k4g5qg8m.skadnetwork</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
<string>s39g8k73mm.skadnetwork</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
<string>3qy4746246.skadnetwork</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
<string>3sh42y64q3.skadnetwork</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
<string>f38h382jlk.skadnetwork</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
<string>hs6bdukanm.skadnetwork</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
<string>prcb7njmu6.skadnetwork</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
<string>v4nxqhlyqp.skadnetwork</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
<string>wzmmz9fp6w.skadnetwork</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
<string>yclnxrl5pm.skadnetwork</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
<string>t38b2kh725.skadnetwork</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
<string>7ug5zh24hu.skadnetwork</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
<string>9rd848q2bz.skadnetwork</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
<string>n6fk4nfna4.skadnetwork</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
<string>kbd757ywx3.skadnetwork</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
<string>9t245vhmpl.skadnetwork</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
<string>4468km3ulz.skadnetwork</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
<string>2u9pt9hc89.skadnetwork</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
<string>8s468mfl3y.skadnetwork</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
<string>av6w8kgt66.skadnetwork</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
<string>klf5c3l5u5.skadnetwork</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
<string>ppxm28t8ap.skadnetwork</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
<string>424m5254lk.skadnetwork</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
<string>uw77j35x4d.skadnetwork</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
<string>578prtvx9j.skadnetwork</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
<string>4dzt52r2t5.skadnetwork</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
<string>e5fvkxwrpn.skadnetwork</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
<string>8c4e2ghe7u.skadnetwork</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
<string>zq492l623r.skadnetwork</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
<string>3qcr597p9d.skadnetwork</string>
</dict>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

AppDelegate:

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import GoogleMobileAds
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
static private(set) var instance: AppDelegate! = nil
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
AppDelegate.instance = self
GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)
return true
}
}
```

BannerView:

```
import SwiftUI
import GoogleMobileAds
final private class BannerVC: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
let view = GADBannerView(adSize: GADAdSizeBanner)
let viewController = UIViewController()
view.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
view.rootViewController = viewController
viewController.view.addSubview(view)
viewController.view.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: GADAdSizeBanner.size)
view.load(GADRequest())
return viewController
}
func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {}
}
struct Banner:View{
var body: some View{
HStack{
Spacer()
Banner().frame(width: 320, height: 50, alignment: .center)
Spacer()
}
}
}
```

ContentView:

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
VStack{
Banner()
}
}
}
```

MainApp:

```
import SwiftUI
@main
struct AdMobTestApp: App {
@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
var body: some Scene {
WindowGroup {
ContentView()
}
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have a message error in console when it crashes? A callstack?

Answer (score 0):

I have been having a similar error when trying to get an Ad SDK working in the simulator. The "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process" error goes away when building to device.

Comment: Adding the CoreTelephony.framework does not seem to help.